# error compiling in prosper

Tags: compiling, presentations, prosper

Where is the error here :

```
\documentclass[pdf,capsules,slideColor,colorBG]{prosper}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Espace de Sobolev $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ }
%\subtitle{LABORATOIRE d EDPNL et HM}
 \author{ hh }
 \email{ @gmail.com }
 \institution{berlin}

\begin{document}


\maketitle

\begin{slide}{ Espace de Sobolev $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$}
$f(x)=\int_a^b\; dx$

\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you didn't run the document with `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf`.
With an up-to-date TeXLive 2015 I get:

[image]

Comment: When i comment the package `tikz` the  program is works

Comment: I use texlive 2015

Comment: The `dvips` driver of `tikZ` is buggy!